# Can I iterate in order on `HashMap<usize, MyStruct>`?

Tags: rust

If I have:

```
my_hash_map: HashMap<usize, MyStruct>,
```

and I do:

```
my_hash_map.iter()
```

I get a `HashMapIter<'_, usize, MyStruct>` that iterates in **arbitrary order**.

Is there a way to iterate in the order of the keys? They are ordered because the key is a `usize`

Comment: Isn't a hash map an unordered data structure?

Comment: @DanielLangr is there a map for ordered keys?

Comment: It seems that you are looking for [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html).

Comment: @Paprika You should have your answer now. I guess you can delete the question (unless you or Daniel wants to write a proper detailed answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HashMap` is an unoredered container, and keeps the items in an arbitrary order. You *cannot* define an order.

If you want sorted iteration, use [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html). If you need insertion order, you can use the [`IndexMap`](https://docs.rs/indexmap/latest/indexmap/map/struct.IndexMap.html) type from the [indexmap](https://lib.rs/crates/indexmap) crate.

Answer (score 4):

Not the best way, but if you **really** need to do it (using plain `HashMap`), you can collect the keys and sort them yourself:

```rust
let mut keys: Vec<usize> = my_hash_map.keys().collect();
keys.sort_unstable();
for k in &keys {
    ... // do your stuff
}
```